# Optimal ways to Traverse through a LinkedList - Java

Tags: java, linked-list, traversal

The Situation

I have a interview with TripAdvisor tomorrow and I decided for practice to create my own custom LinkedList. I'm trying to figure out the best way to traverse through it.

Primary Question: I have managed to traverse through my Linked List however I believe
there is a better way to do it. How would you traverse through it ?

Bonus Question: How do my overall classes look ? Is there anything I should/should not add ?
It seems to work fine but is it optimal ?

Bonus Question #2: Lastly I was wondering if anyonehad any insight to typical interview questions/concepts that I must know ?

Greatly appreciated.

Here are my Classes

```
// *********************************Node Class*******************************************     
 public class Node<T> {
  Node<T> link;

  T data;

  public Node(T data) {

    this.data = data;
    link = null;

}

public T getData() {
    return data;

}

public Node<T> getLink() {

    return link;

}


public Node<T> setLink(Node<T> N) {

    this.link = N;
    return link;

}

public void setData(T newData) {

    this.data = newData;

}
```

}

```
    //****************************************Linked List Class*******************************

   public class LinkedList<T> {

Node<T> head;
T data;


public LinkedList(){
   head = null;
   }




public void add(T data){

    Node<T> newNode = new Node<T> (data);
    newNode.setLink(head);
    head = newNode;
}


  //had problems printing out the data in the last node

 public void traverse(){
    Node<T> pointer;
    pointer = head;

while (pointer.getLink()!=null){
        System.out.println(pointer.getData());
        pointer = pointer.setLink(pointer.getLink());
}

//Fixed problems For last node that doesnt get printed out
System.out.println(pointer.getData());

}
```

//Again is there a better way to do this ?
   //Thanks
}

Comment: What position are you interviewing for?

Comment: Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why can't you just use `pointer = pointer.getLink();`, and `while (pointer != null) {` (and remove your last Print statement)

Comment: Interview questions involving linked lists usually focus on the "Remove" operation because it has some interesting edge-cases. Also a common interview question to follow something like this would be: "How would you detect a circular linked list, or one which contains a cycle?"

Comment: @omalsa04 Thanks for the insight! Can't believe I didnt think of that solution myself

Comment: @PM77-1 A java development internship position

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would change your traverse function to be more like this:

```
public void traverse(){
  Node<T> pointer = head;

  while (pointer != null){
    System.out.println(pointer.getData());
    pointer = pointer.getLink();
  }
}
```

Also it is common to represent the Node class as a private inner class of LinkedList because it is not typically needed anywhere else.

As far as the interview itself goes, traversal questions are more typical for binary-trees (eg. print out the elements in sorted order). LinkedList questions are more focussed on the remove/insert operations which both require careful attention to the edge cases (what happens when you remove the head for example). A more advanced LinkedList question would ask how to detect a cycle, I would make sure that I knew at least one method of doing this (have a look at the [Tortoise and the Hare algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Tortoise_and_hare)).

**EDIT:**

Algorithm questions will nearly always be from the following list:

- String manipulation such as:

  - Reverse String
  - Count how many times each letter appears in a given String (use a Map for this)
- LinkedList questions such as:

  - How to remove a node, pay close attention to edge cases such as removing the head
  - How to reverse a linkedList (make the Tail the Head)
- Binary Tree questions such as:

  - In-order traversal
  - If there is a BTree balancing question you won't need to implement it, just understand that a completely unbalanced Binary Tree is simply a Linked List.
  - Understand that searching a balanced Binary Tree is O(log n) compared to a Linked List or a completely unbalanced Binary Tree which is O(n).
- You will probably be asked to describe the complexity of the solution you just gave (big-O notation)

See [this](http://www.allapplabs.com/interview_questions/java_interview_questions.htm) and [this](https://www.udemy.com/blog/java-interview-questions/) for questions related to Java itself

Comment: Just one addition here, that Node is generally implemented as private static class Not private inner class. --> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html and now I am a nitpicker :) Quoting Joshua Bloch's Effective Java - Item 22*: Favor static member classes over nonstatic.